# MYSQL query: count the dates

Tags: sql, mysql

In the table below

```
+-------+-----------------------+ 
| id    | timestamp             | 
+-------+-----------------------+ 
| 1     | 2010-06-10 14:35:30   | 
| 2     | 2010-06-10 15:27:35   | 
| 3     | 2010-06-10 16:39:36   | 
| 4     | 2010-06-11 14:55:30   | 
| 5     | 2010-06-11 18:45:31   | 
| 6     | 2010-06-12 20:25:31   | 
+-------+-----------------------+
```

I want to be able to count the dates (time is ignored). So the output should be like below:

```
+-------+-----------------------+ 
| id    | type         | count  |
+-------+-----------------------+ 
| 1     | 2010-06-10   | 3      |
| 2     | 2010-06-11   | 2      |
| 3     | 2010-06-12   | 1      |
+-------+-----------------------+
```

What would be the query for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works if you can live without the `id` column in the result:

```
SELECT DATE(timestamp) AS type, COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM sometable
GROUP BY DATE(timestamp)
ORDER BY DATE(timestamp)
```

Comment: @MvanGeest, you don't need a distinct here because you are doing GROUP BY!

Comment: @VoodooChild: No, the reason you don't need DISTINCT here is because there are no joins.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: Well he could have done [SELECT DISTINCT (DATE(timestamp)) from sometable] INSTEAD OF [SELECT (DATE(timestamp) as t from sometable group by t], which would produce the same result. So in this sense, he would not need distinct when using group by!

Comment: This is correct. You don't need order by DATE(timestamp) because group by will automatically order it anyway (in mysql at least). Except if you want another order, such as `order by 2 desc`, to get the most frequent days first.

Comment: @VoodooChild : I was not replying to your discussion, I was pointing to the fact that Ignacio's answer is correct and made a further suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    DATE(timestamp),
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    My_Table
GROUP BY
    DATE(timestampe)
```

This doesn't give you a row number for each row. I don't know if (why?) that's important.

Answer (score 0):

```
select date(timestamp) as type, count(*)
from your_table
group by type;
```

Comment: I doubt if alias name can be directly used in the GROUP BY Clause

Comment: @Madhivanan: MySQL supports the use of aliases from the SELECT clause in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, and HAVING clauses. From the manual: `A select_expr can be given an alias using AS alias_name. The alias is used as the expression's column name and can be used in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses.`

Answer (score 0):

This might work...

```
select DATE(timestamp), count(timestamp)
    from _table
group by timestamp
order by count(timestamp) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT count( DATE_FORMAT( timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d/' ) ) , DATE_FORMAT( timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d' )
FROM tablename
group by DATE_FORMAT( timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d' );

You can not include the id in the select or the count will be off.